# Send actions to the Application controller in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to toggle a global property on the application controller, by clicking a button on one of the templates. I've read some stuff on action bubbling but can't it to work.

Here's the property and action on the Application controller

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isAuthenticated: true,
  actions: {
    logIn: function(){
      this.toggleProperty('isAuthenticated');
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the action with a login.hbs template file (I'll turn this into a proper button soon)

```
<span {{action 'logIn'}}>
    {{#link-to 'boards' class="btn-l bg-blue white db mtl link bn w-100"}}Login{{/link-to}}
</span>
```

How could I ensure the action toggles the property on the Application Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your login controller,you need to inject application controller.

```
 import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
   appCont:Ember.inject.controller('application')
 });
```

and in login.hbs you need to specify which target will receive the method call.

```
<button {{action 'logIn' target=appCont}}> Login </button>
```

In this `<button {{action 'logIn'}}> Login </button>` , context of a template is login controller, actions used this way will bubble to login route when the login controller does not implement the specified action. Once an action hits a login route, it will bubble through the route hierarchy.

Reference: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_specifying-a-target

EDIT: If you want to call functions available in `Controller` inside `Component then you need to pass actions to`Component`

> Login.hbs

```
{{component-a logIn=(action 'logIn') }}
```

> component-a.hbs

```
<button {{action (action logIn)}}> LogIn</button>
```

Comment: or in a function like this.get('foreigncontroller').send("actionname",parameter1, parameter2...);

if foreigncontroller is injected or provided anyhow

Comment: Would this work in the same way with with a button within a component?

Comment: @jermainecraig No. since you can't inject controller inside Component. for this you need to use closure actions that should be sent from template.hbs to component..

Comment: @jermainecraig updated my answer to call controller actions from component.